# How to avoid many connections when using high number of queue workers?

Tags: mysql, laravel, redis

Probably I'm missing something obvious but I had an architecture problem.

I'm building uptime monitoring service.

I have monitors table, each monitor represents a URL. My task it to send http request to the url. I send http requests from multiple servers. Each servers will handle like thousands of urls per minute.

So, in every server I have supervisord which spawns, say, 50-100 queue workers. Once per minute I push to the queue all monitors, and then these monitors are being checked by the queue workers.

However, each queue worker creates a connection to MySQL. I think this is because I pass Monitor model to the queue Job, and Laravel puts only monitor id into the queue. Then it retrieves whole monitor model from database when the job is being handled.

Or probably I'm mistaken and the reason is just because laravel connects by default when running any kind of code, including queued Jobs.

But 10 servers * 100 workers = 1000 connections, which is probably bad (I don't know for sure, but I assume that it's not scalable).

My queues based on local redis.

So I thought that it's reasonable to put serialized model data in redis. Then, the result of http requests I put in redis. Then push bunch of results at once in MySQL.

So how to achieve that?

Comment: Why are web requests going through a worker queue system rather than processing the request inline?  Web requests are already a spawned worker thread of a sort. Ensure your database retrieval is quick (it looks like a simple indexed lookup) and the connect web connection will be significantly higher than the database connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Like, okay, once per minute I need to run 1000 requests. If I do it right inside php script in a for loop, then they will be kind of synchronous, no? I saw guzzle have some kind of async requests, but it's easier to work with queued jobs as a single object/place where I handle 1 monitor, no?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with my understanding of your architecture. It looks like each worker, pulls a monitor information based on  monitor_id (why not just this in the queue?), performs a probe which take some time, and then pushes the result back to mysql.

Comment: 1000 connections isn't too bad when most of the time they are idle or doing a simple insert/single row select/update.

Comment: It pulls job from queue which has monitor (I think Laravel keeps only monitor_id and then fetches the whole model from mysql), then performs a probe, then pushes the result  to Redis. Then once per second I push all made checks which are kept in Redis to mysql (kind of bunch insert instead of single, for improving performance)

Well, if I have high number of monitors then these connections will do many like say 3000 selects from database.

Though I'm not exactly sure how everything works under the hood, I thought that it's reasonable to keep whole monitor model in redis queue, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before dispatching the jobs you fetch all the related models(in chunks) and dispatch the jobs with the model instance that you need in the job. So you won't need to fetch the model again from the database while processing the job.

One of the key thing is that, you shouldn't use `SerializesModels` trait inside your job class if you are going to send the model instance. As it is stated in the [documentation](http://%20https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#class-structure)

> **If your queued job accepts an Eloquent model in its constructor, only the identifier for the model will be serialized onto the queue**. When the job is actually handled, the queue system will automatically re-retrieve the full model instance and its loaded relationships from the database.

If the `handle` method doesn't have any database related dependency, then it won't open a connection to your database. If you are using `mysql` you can then try `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to examine it. I checked on my local(with `sleep`), it doesn't show any mysql process.

Comment: ERSOY! It's so good feeling when I figured it out myself and then read your post and you proved everything I did like line by line! I removed SerializesModels, and now I have full model info in redis. But I also managed to just pass a plain object/array to the job, so now it works fine without models.

Thank you!!!